# std map find is always true

Tags: c++, qt, stl, find, stdmap

I have a problem using the std::map, specifically when using find.
I have the following code.

```
class MyClass
{
    update(const QVariant&);
    QVariant m_itemInfo;
    std::map<QVariant, int> m_testMap;
}

void update(const QVariant& itemInfo)
{
    if(m_itemInfo != itemInfo)
    {
         // The items are not equal
         m_itemInfo = itemInfo;
    }
    if(m_testMap.find(itemInfo) == m_testMap.end())
    {
        // TestMap doesnt contain key itemInfo.
        m_testMap.insert(std::make_pair(itemInfo, 1));
    }

    // More code
}
```

The function `update` is called several times (with different itemInfo objects) in my code. Now when I start to debug it, I see that the first time `update` is called, both the first and the second if loop are entered. So far so good. However the second time `update` is called I do see that the first if loop is called, but the second is skipped! What am I missing here?

Comment: Show the `operator==` of your QVariant, and you could also edit a little bit to make a MCVE [ http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ].

Comment: The success/failure of `if(m_testMap.find(itemInfo) == m_testMap.end())` depends on behavior of `QVariant::operator<`. It's hard telling what could be wrong without seeing a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So it is dependent on operator<, and not operator==?

Comment: @Frank By default, `std::map` considers two elements, `a` and `b`, equal if and only if `!(a < b)` and `!(b < a)`. If your `QVariant`s are not comparable, they are probably equal in `std::map`'s eyes and you need `std::unordered_map` or `QHash` or a custom comparator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem that the first and second `QVariant`s that you pass to your Update method have different type (for example, `bool` and `uint`). `std::map::find` doesn't use !=operator to compare keys, it uses operator < (less) by default. If two compared `QVariant` values have different types operators != and < may work contradictory.
`std::map::find` compares keys in the following way:

> Two keys are considered equivalent if the container's comparison object returns false reflexively (i.e., no matter the order in which the elements are passed as arguments).

i.e. `std::map::find` considers that v1 is equal to v2

```
    if(!(v1<v2) && !(v2>v1)) { //is TRUE !!!
    }
```

To solve your problem, you should define a *less* comparison for `std:map`.

```
    class QVariantLessCompare {
        bool operator()(const QVariant&  v1, QVariant& v2) const {
           // ==== You SHOULD IMPLEMENT appropriate comparison here!!! ====
           // Implementation will depend on type of QVariant values you use 
           //return v1 < v2;
       }
    };
```

And use `QVariantCompare` in a such way:

```
    std::map<QVariant, int, QVariantLessCompare> m_testMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more paradigmatic solution is to use `QMap` which correctly implements the comparison of most `QVariant` types. It won't do `userTypes()` out of the box, but this still might suit your application.

A cleaner version of the solution proposed by Володин Андрей, that builds, might look like:

```
struct QVariantLessCompare {
    bool operator()(const QVariant& v1,const QVariant& v2) const 
    {
        return v1.toInt() < v2.toInt();
    }
};
```